# Application is getting crash while presenting view controller modally

Tags: html, ios, webview

I am getting following exception when I am presenting modal view controller:

> "**Application tried to present modally an active controller <ViewController: 0x16e9d270>**"

But this crash is occurs only in one case.

Basically I am adding subview (webview) to the presented controller.
All loading of html contents, webview delegate methods implementation etc. is done in another class.

I am passing the webview object, which I am receiving In webViewDidFinishLoad method to the presenting view controller to add it into the to be presented controller's subview.

It is working, but app is getting crash if below html response is received from server:

`<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<iframe frameborder="0" width="300" height="250" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" target="_blank" scrolling="no" src="http://nym1.mobile.adnxs.com/if?e=wqT_3QKHBPBC_gEAAAIA1gAFCNnhtKYFEKmko7ePueCUbRikrovh65Dzh38gASotCeF6FK5H4co_EYqw4emVssQ_GQAAAAAAAPA_IRESBCnhDSSwMPK4-QE4rhVA7AdIAlDD4e0LWMr-ImAGaLPkA3AAeOrWAoABAYoBA1VTRJIBAQbwb5gBrAKgAfoBqAEGsAEAuAEBwAEFyAEA0AEA2AEA4AEA8AEAigJ0dWYoJ2EnLCA0NTEyMjQsIDE0MjI3MzM1MjkpO3VmKCdjJywgNjk4NjYzNCwgMTQyMjczMzUyOSk7dWYoJ2cnLCAxNzEwMTAxLCA-HQAocicsIDI0ODY3MDE6HgDwipICnQEhaVNhX2ZBaUt0Nm9ERU1QaDdRc1lBQ0RLX2lJd0FEZ0FRQUJJN0FkUThyajVBVmdBWU13RWFBQndBSGdBZ0FFQWlBRUFrQUVCbUFFQm9BRUJxQUVEc0FFQXVRSGhlaFN1Ui1IS1A4RUI0WG9VcmtmaHlqX0pBWVYxbWJIVHl2NF8yUUVBQUEBAyREd1AtQUJBUFVCAQ4wQUEuLpoCHSF4UVo2UDqgALh5djRpSUFBLtgCAOACrqQcgAMAiAMBkAMAmAMAoAMAqgMAsAMAuAMAwAOsAsgDAQ..&dlo=1"></iframe>');</script>`

Application is not crashing if I do all the webview delegate methods implementation in the to be presented view controller. Means loads the html contents in the modal view controller itself.

Unable to understand the reason of crash

Comment: What is the crash log?

Comment: Below message print on console -Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <ViewController: 0x16d37f40>.'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x28b7549f 0x3632bc8b 0x2c319ab5 0x2c31b587 0x2c11f5e1 0x2c148bc1 0x2c147ba9 0x2c147a3b 0x2c147529 0x2c06b4ed 0x2c06b3ff 0x2ba642d9 0x2299c7 0x22d3ed 0x28b3b3b1 0x28b39ab1 0x28a873c1 0x28a871d3 0x2fe850a9 0x2c096fa1 0xe387d 0x368abaaf)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your passing the web view object to the presented view controller but this object's delegate still referencing to the presenting view controller and that's the issue.

Comment: I cannot set delegate to nil because I have to perform some action on webview click action

Comment: Check if the didFinisLoading is getting called twice.

Comment: Yes, didFinishLoading is getting called twice in some cases and application is crashing.

Comment: And that's the issue. The second time it calls back it tried to modally present the already presented view.

Comment: Thanks Ashraf. Now I able to resolve this issue by checking if controller is already presented.